# How to make cell array from two tables?

Tags: matlab

How do I generate a cell array from two separate tables?

I have a dataset from Excel comprised of **numbers** that looks something like this:

```
A1 A3 A5 A7 A9
A2 A4 A6 A8 A0
```

and

```
B1 B3 B5 B7 B9
B2 B4 B6 B8 B0
```

Where A7 or B0 are just stand-ins for the numbers.

I can import them as tables as separate 'table' variable, but in the end
I want to create a cell array like so:

```
[A1,B1] [A3,B3] [A5,B5] [A7,B7] [A9,B9]
[A2,B2] [A4,B4] [A6,B6] [A8,B8] [A0,B0]
```

How would I best do this?
Thank you!

Comment: What you need for a "minimum reproducible example" is actual Matlab code that we can run to reproduce your issue. Instead of just laying out those "A1 A3 A5..." numbers, provide a Matlab expression that will generate them. Like this: `some_nums = [1 3 5 7 9; 2 4 6 8 10]; a_table = array2table(some_nums)`. Then we can copy and paste your code into our Matlab sessions and see exactly what's happening, and give you back exact code that you can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the tables to arrays, and then zip them together using `arrayfun`:

```matlab
% Here's your example tables:
a = reshape(1:10, [2 5]);
b = reshape(11:20, [2 5]);
ta = array2table(a);
tb = array2table(b);

% Convert them to arrays:
a1 = table2array(ta);
b1 = table2array(tb);

% Zip them together with arrayfun:
c = arrayfun(@(x,y) {[x,y]}, a1, b1)
```

Or more succinctly, skip the table2array step:

```matlab
c = arrayfun(@(x,y) {[x,y]}, ta.Variables, tb.Variables);
```

The results:

```
>> c = arrayfun(@(x,y) {[x,y]}, a1, b1)
c =
  2×5 cell array
    {1×2 double}    {1×2 double}    {1×2 double}    {1×2 double}    {1×2 double}
    {1×2 double}    {1×2 double}    {1×2 double}    {1×2 double}    {1×2 double}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `table2array` calls and just use `a1.Variables` and `b1.Variables`

Comment: I learned something new today! Edited to add your technique.

Comment: What is the purpose of the reshape part of the code? Is it to simply convert them into arrays?

Comment: The `reshape` takes `1:10` or `11:20`, which is a 1-by-10 array, and converts it to a 2-by-5 array, so it's shaped like your example input.